# Bypass not_found filter in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am trying to configure Sinatra to

1. Show a simple 404 string in all requests that are not found.
2. Send a custom 404 video file in one route, when the route fails to fulfill the request.

The minimal code to show the issue:

```
# somefile.txt
some content

# server.rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'

set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
set :port, 3000

not_found do
  content_type :text
  "404 Not Found"
end

get '/test' do
  # in reality this is a video file, not a text file.

  # .. do some work here, and if failed, send 404 file ...

  # this does not work, since it triggers the not_found filter above
  send_file "somefile.txt", type: :text, status: 404

  # this works, but with 200 instead of 404
  # send_file "somefile.txt", type: :text
end
```

The `not_found` filter captures everything, even the `send_file ... status: 404`

To me, this seems a little like a bug in `send_file`, but perhaps I am wrong.

Is there a way to state "skip the not_found filter", or any other more appropriate way to achieve this?

Keep in mind, in reality, this server should return a not found video file, not a text file. I used text here just for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a bug, as [documentation](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html) states,

> When a `Sinatra::NotFound` exception is raised, or the response’s status code is 404, the `not_found` handler is invoked:

I suppose that you can solve problem by replacing `not_found` override with error handling like this:

```
error Sinatra::NotFound do
  content_type :text
  "404 Not Found"
end
```

This should trigger only on error, not on response code.

Comment: Thanks. Elegant solution.